# Как задать элементам ID с условием первого не повторяющегося далее символа?

Tags: javascript

Имеются несколько заголовков, у которых первые символы - числа.
Числа могут повторяться несколько раз в качестве первых символов в каждом новом заголовке.

Как сделать, чтобы атрибут ***id*** задавался только тем заголовкам, у которых число 1, 2, 3 и т.д. встречается впервые?

Например, чтобы из:

```html
<h2>1 сезон, 1 серия</h2>
<h2>1 сезон, 2 серия</h2>
<h2>2 сезон, 1 серия</h2>
<h2>2 сезон, 2 серия</h2>
```

Получалось:

```html
<h2 id="sezon-1">1 сезон, 1 серия</h2>
<h2>1 сезон, 2 серия</h2>
<h2 id="sezon-2">2 сезон, 1 серия</h2>
<h2>2 сезон, 2 серия</h2>
```

Comment: Разметка точно такая, как в примере или сложнее? "Сезон, серия и тд." - всегда присутствуют и всегда в том же порядке?

Comment: Пора уже включать в вопросы попытки решений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('h2')].filter(el => /\D1 серия/gim.test(el.textContent)).forEach(el => el.setAttribute('id', el.textContent.replace(/^(\d+).*/m, 'sezon-$1')));

console.log([...document.querySelectorAll('h2')]);
```

```html
<h2>1 сезон, 1 серия</h2>
<h2>1 сезон, 2 серия</h2>
<h2>2 сезон, 1 серия</h2>
<h2>2 сезон, 2 серия</h2>
```